# Change names of PySpark dataframe columns and pass them pandas

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using pyspark to read some data using:

```
data = spark.read.option("delimiter", "|").option("header","true").parquet(File)
```

then I use this to eliminate the points in the name of the coluns

```
names_data = data.columns
j=0
for i in names_data:
  new = i.replace(".","_")
  names_data[j] = new
  j=j+1
  data = data.withColumnRenamed(i,new)
```

Finally I want to pass this data to pandas

```
x = data.toPandas()
```

But I get

```
Exception: could not open socket
```

Answer (score 1):

To replace the column names with special characters in data frame. You can do like below

```
# special characters to be replaced in data frame
reps = ('.', '_')

# Find column names of data frame
columns_to_replace = df.schema.names

# function to replace special characters in the data frame
def col_rename(x):
    new_columns = reduce(lambda a, kv: a.replace(*kv), reps, x)
    return (re.sub('.', '_', x) if new_columns
            in columns_to_replace else new_columns)

# Apply col_rename function to data frame
for i in columns_to_replace:
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(i, col_rename(i))
```

Then you can convert the `pyspark` data frame to `pandas` like below

```
pandas_df = df.toPandas()
```